# android camera2 associate TotalCaptureResult with Frame

Tags: android, api, camera

this is regarding Android's Camera2 APIs. Since capture result and output frame are produced asynchronously, one could get capture result much before the actual frame. Is there a good way to associate produced frame with the corresponding capture result ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about a frame that is sent to an `ImageReader` or `SurfaceTexture` upon capture (as in the ubiquitous [camera2basic](http://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Basic/index.html) example), the trick is to compare unique timestamps identifying the images.

1. Save the `TotalCaptureResult` somewhere accessible when it is available in your `CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback`'s `onCaptureComplete(...)` call.
2. Then, when the actual image is available via your `ImageReader.OnAvailableListener` or `SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener`, get the image's timestamp:

`Long imageTimestamp = Long.valueOf(reader.acquireNextImage().getTimestamp());` or

`Long imageTimestamp = Long.valueOf(surfaceTexture.getTimestamp())`, respectively.

3. Compare timestamps with: `imageTimestamp.equals(totalCaptureResult.get(CaptureResult.SENSOR_TIMESTAMP));`

Notes:

- The timestamp may not be an actual true system timestamp for your device, but it is guaranteed to be unique and monotonically increasing, so it works as an ID.
- If you are sending the image to a `SurfaceHolder` or something else instead, you're out of luck as only the pixel information gets sent, not the timestamp present in the `Image` object. I'm not sure about the other places you can send a frame, e.g., `MediaRecorder` or `Allocation`, but I think not.
- You probably need to add each new `TotalCaptureResult` to a growing set as they are generated, and then compare an incoming image's timestamp against all of these, because of the asynchronous nature you noted. I'll let you figure out how to do that as you see fit.

Comment: In my case image reader callback comes before onCaptureCompleted is called. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

I had to solve a similar situation (sync frames across surfaces); Sumner's solution (`.getTimestamp()` of the respective received Image object) did the trick for me for `SurfaceTexture` and `ImageReader`.

Just a quick note on other surfaces (which, as pointed out, don't give you an `Image` object): at least for `MediaCodec`, the [`BufferInfo`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.BufferInfo.html) object received by the [`onOutputBufferAvailable` callback](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.Callback.html#onOutputBufferAvailable%28android.media.MediaCodec,%20int,%20android.media.MediaCodec.BufferInfo%29) has a `presentationTimeUs`, which is "derived from the presentation timestamp passed in with the corresponding input buffer" and, at least for me, *appears* to match the timestamps from other surfaces. (Note the different unit though.)