# Android Camera 2 API CaptureResult Synchronization with Output Surfaces

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm currently developing an algorithm in computational photography that requires IMU data for denoising purposes.
I set the infamous [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Video) project as my start base and I'm using the android monotonic clock that provided in callbacks from sensors as a comparison origin in the case that we're dealing with IMU.

When overriding the [onCaptureComplete](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback#onCaptureCompleted(android.hardware.camera2.CameraCaptureSession,%20android.hardware.camera2.CaptureRequest,%20android.hardware.camera2.TotalCaptureResult)) Callback I can access the sensor's first light timestamp and more at the same time base as the IMU data reported. The problem arises when in the CaptureRequest.Builder, we set the target for example to the surface of a  MediaRecorder instance.

How I can understand in the recorded media that which frame is which? for example in my case that is basically the same source code as the base project, I recorded 107 times onCaptureComplete callback and surprisingly the recorded media contains 113 frames (using ffprobe).

There is a similar problem discussed before in this matter here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28960172/android-camera2-associate-totalcaptureresult-with-frame). for example, one might say that just record the Preview SurfaceTexture, but the time stamp that this class is providing isn't exactly the sensors timestamp as suggested in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture#getTimestamp()).